# ableton put insert marker at current position

Tags: ableton-live

Is there a keycommand or midi command for placing the "insert marker" (the red triangle) at the current play position.  As opposed to clicking with the mouse.  I want to scroll to a position with my control surface and then set the insert marker without reaching for the mouse.